# Generating random numbers in a range with a predefined, non-uniform probability

Tags: c++, boost, probability

I want to generate random numbers in the range 1-10. 
The requirement is that 70% of the numbers shud be generated in the range 1-3 and the remaining 30% in the range 4-10. 
I am using boost to generate probability distributions. What prob dist should I use and what parameters?

Comment: Well, what you can do is extend your range so that you are actually generating from 1-100, and if you come up with a number in the 70% range, split that between 1-3 (say, 1-23 is a 1, 24-47 is a 2, 48-70 is a 3; same idea for 4-10...not the most elegant, but it'd work. Or learn probability distributions, pdf, cdf, and all that fun stuff.

Comment: This seems to be documented quite well? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_with_different_probabilities

Comment: Are you interested in whole numbers or floating point ones?

Comment: Your problem statement is under-specified. If you pick 1 with proba 70% and 10 with proba 30%, it will technically satisfy your requirements (1 is in 1-3 range, 10 in 4-10 range). Do you want the numbers to be uniformly distributed over 1-3, and over 4-10? Are we talking integers or floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the code I found in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_with_different_probabilities), I believe something along these lines should solve the problem:

```
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/discrete_distribution.hpp>

int main() {
  double probabilities[] = {
      0.7/3, 0.7/3, 0.7/3, 0.3/7, 0.3/7, 0.3/7, 0.3/7, 0.3/7, 0.3/7, 0.3/7
  };
  boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist(probabilities);

  /* For each number to generate: */
  int number = dist(gen) + 1; // to get range 1-10 rather than 0-9

  return 0;
}
```

Strictly speaking, what this does is it assigns a 70% probability to the numbers 1-3 (70% of the probability mass are being equally distributed among 1, 2 and 3), and 30% to 4-10 (again, equally distributed among them). That does not guarantee that 70% of the numbers you get are 1-3 and 30% are 4-10. It just means the output is likely to converge to that distribution as it grows.

If you want to actually guarantee that exactly 70% of the numbers are 1-3 and 30% are 4-6, you'd have to define two uniform distributions:

```
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist1(1, 3);
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist2(4, 10);
```

Then, to generate N random numbers, you could draw `N*0.7` times from `dist1`, and `N*0.3` times from `dist2`, put all of these numbers into a `std::vector` and apply `std::random_shuffle()`. This would guarantee the 70:30 requirement (except for a possible rounding error depending on N).

Comment: @AlexanderChertov's comment above makes a good point. My solution assumes you want integers only. If you are interested in floating point numbers, the approach described above will not work.

Comment: A similar answer using list of probabilities can be seen http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution. This time instead of boost new c++ standard is used